# Unable to fetch __r records in dataloader

Tags: soql, data-loader

I am using query in data loader but unable to fetch __r records from database i only gets __c records only

```
SELECT Model__c.Name, Model__c.Widget__r.Name from Model__c
```

Comment: its not possible to fetch the related object records in data loader, maybe u can create a formula field temporarily to populate the value of that field, and delete it once your work is over with the data loader.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible fetch relationship values in the dataloader if the bulk api is not used.

There is a configuration setting called sfdc.useBulkApi in the process-conf.xml that controls this, if this value is set to false then relationship values can be retrieved.

In the dataloader UI this can be found in the Settings menu and is called "Use Bulk API", it should be unticked when retrieving relationship values.